# How to create a validator function that calls two functions to confirm login (email/passwd) info?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two functions created already (isEmailValid & isPasswordValid) below which I could use some feedback on as well.I'm supposed to have them return a boolean value (if they follow the correct format). This would then get passed on to the Validator function which is supposed to analyze a loadData function with entries in LocalStorage to see if the email/password combo matches.

**Email & Password Functions:**

```
function isEmailValid(email) {
        var res1;
    var emailText = document.email.value;
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
    if (pattern.test(emailText)) 
            {
            res1 = "TRUE";
        } else {
            res1 = "FALSE";
        }
}

function isPasswordValid(passwd) { 
     var res2; 
     var str = document.passwd.value; 
     if (str.match(/[a-z]/g) && str.match(/[A-Z]/g) && str.match(/[0-9]/g) && str.match(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/g) && str.length >= 8) 
            res2 = "TRUE"; 
     else 
            res2 = "FALSE"; 
                            }
```

**loadData function**

```
function loadData()
{
  var coordinators = [
     {
        email: "jjd@gmail.com",
        firstName: "Jennifer",
        lastname: "Davis",
        role: "instructor",
        password:"anoth3rpass"
   },

   {
      email: "boss_man@yahoo.com",
      firstName: "Anderson",
      surname: "Alleyne",
      role: "instructor",
      password:"passw0rd"
   }
  ]

  var students = [
   {
      year: "2018",
      student_id: "220249309",
      firstName: "Merissa",
      lastName: "Halliwall",
      email: "mm_h@hotmail.com",
      password:"f1rstpa55",
      address: "Lodge Road Ch Ch"
   },

   {
      year: "2020",
      student_id: "408306622",
      firstName: "Vanda",
      lastName: "Marshall",
      email: "vmarhsall@guardian.co.uk",
      password:"oll1p0ps",
      address: "Sargeants Village Tenantry Ch Ch"
   },

   {
      year: "2019",
      student_id: "210350493",
      firstName: "Mark",
      lastName: "Belgrave",
      email: "bboy89@hotmail.com",
      password:"246bajan",
      address: "76 Edghill Terrace"
   },

   {
      year: "2020",
      student_id: "200006059",
      firstName: "Pamale",
      lastName: "Gaskin",
      email: "pamgask99@gmail.com",
      password:"pamal3gask",
      address: "Lot 33 The Belle"
   }
}

  //add to localStorage 
  if(!localStorage.getItem("coordinators"))
  {
     localStorage.setItem("coordinators", JSON.stringify(coordinators));
  }
  if(!localStorage.getItem("students"))
  {
     localStorage.setItem("students", JSON.stringify(students));
  }

}
```

There are coordinators (admins) and students. I'm supposed to have the login page take you to different sites depending on which you are.

I am just a bit lost on how to create the Validator function...

Comment: You can specify the pattern as an HTML attribute of the input, you don't have to do that with JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Comment: @DaCurse It's for an assignment, so that was his requirement.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from you question is if email validation and password validation is successful then you want to do some action otherwise another. I have written a simple code that may help you to structure you code.

```
var emailValidate = function() {
    var x = 1;
    if (x === 2) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  var passValidate = function() {
    var y = 1;
    if (y === 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  function allValidate() {
    var isEmailValidate = emailValidate();
    var isPassValidate = passValidate();

    if (isEmailValidate && isPassValidate) {
      console.log("Pass");
    } else {
      console.log("Fail");
    }
  }

  allValidate();
```

Comment: You're only using `emailValidate()` and `passValidate()` once inside `allValidate()`. Which means you could simply use them inside the condition, instead of assigning them to some useless vars. Even if you assign them, you should use `const`, not `var`, since you never reassign. And, since it's a pure function, it could be a `const` instead of `function`: `const allValidate = () => console.log(emailValidate() && passValidate() ? 'Pass' : 'Fail' ); allValidate();`

Answer (score -1):

**Note:** I see it's for an assignment. But here are some disclaimers:

- Never do this in the real world, this is not secure at all. User credentials should never be exposed client-side (in JS). They should be checked server-side.
- Your password validation function requires passwords to have at least a lower case letter, an upper case letter, a number, no special characters, and have a length of 8 at minimum. But in your example users, none of them respect that rule (no uppercase). So that won't work.

Here are things I noticed:

1. First, you need to fix your two validator functions, which don't `return` anything. You're creating `res1` and `res2` variables, but not doing anything with them?
2. Instead of returning Strings (`"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"`), you should use Booleans (`true` or `false`).
3. Taking the above tips into account, you can simplify this kind of code:

```
if (x) { return true; } else { return false; }
```

into:

```js
return x; // Much shorter, isn't it?
```

4. You're declaring `email` and `passwd` parameters for your functions, but you're not using them. You'll have better control over the reusability of your code if you extract the knowledge of the DOM (HTML) from them. Pass Strings, and just use those Strings.
5. Your `isValidPassword` uses `match`, which either returns an Array or `null`. For your purpose, it would make more sense to use `test`, which returns a Boolean.
6. In Regex (Regular expression), to check for the presence of a single character, you don't need the `g` flag (global)
7. This regex: `/[^a-zA-Z\d]/`, and especially the `[^` part means that the password should not contain any character present between those brackets. Here is a version which would make more sense: `/^[a-zA-Z\d]+$/`. It requires that between the beginning (`^`) and the end (`$`), there should be one or more (`+`) of only those characters.

If I take all of this into account, this is how I would do it (you can try it using the blue button below):

```js
// Minified in this example, for clarity
var coordinators = [{email:"jjd@gmail.com",firstName:"Jennifer",lastname:"Davis",role:"instructor",password:"anoth3rpass"},{email:"boss_man@yahoo.com",firstName:"Anderson",surname:"Alleyne",role:"instructor",password:"passw0rd"}];
var students = [{year:"2018",student_id:"220249309",firstName:"Merissa",lastName:"Halliwall",email:"mm_h@hotmail.com",password:"f1rstpa55",address:"Lodge Road Ch Ch"},{year:"2020",student_id:"408306622",firstName:"Vanda",lastName:"Marshall",email:"vmarhsall@guardian.co.uk",password:"oll1p0ps",address:"Sargeants Village Tenantry Ch Ch"},{year:"2019",student_id:"210350493",firstName:"Mark",lastName:"Belgrave",email:"bboy89@hotmail.com",password:"246bajan",address:"76 Edghill Terrace"},{year:"2020",student_id:"200006059",firstName:"Pamale",lastName:"Gaskin",email:"pamgask99@gmail.com",password:"pamal3gask",address:"Lot 33 The Belle"},{year:"2020",student_id:"200006060",firstName:"Mayas",lastName:"Knaizeh",email:"mayas.k@gmail.com",password:"Mayas4ever",address:"Lot 33 The Belle"}];

var emailInput  = document.getElementById('email'),
    passwdInput = document.getElementById('passwd'),
    loginBtn    = document.getElementById('login-btn');

// When the user clicks on the button, execute loadData
loginBtn.addEventListener('click', loadData);
  
function isEmailValid(email) {
  var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
  return pattern.test(email);
}

function isPasswordValid(passwd) {
  return (
    /[a-z]/.test(passwd) &&
    /[A-Z]/.test(passwd) &&
    /[0-9]/.test(passwd) &&
    /^[a-zA-Z\d]+$/.test(passwd) &&
    passwd.length >= 8
  );
}

function areValidCredentials(email, passwd) {
  return isEmailValid(email) && isPasswordValid(passwd);
}

function findUserInList(list, email, passwd) {
  return list.find(function (user) {
    return user.email === email && user.password === passwd;
  });
}

function loadData() {
  var email  = emailInput.value,
      passwd = passwdInput.value,
      valid  = areValidCredentials(email, passwd),
      // We'll fill those in below
      coordinator,
      student;
  
  if (!valid) {
    // We return, because there is nothing else to do
    return alert("Invalid user/password format. Please check and try again.");
  }
  // Look for a coordinator with the same email/password
  coordinator = findUserInList(coordinators, email, passwd);
  
  if (coordinator) {
    alert("Welcome " + coordinator.firstName + "! You are a coordinator.");
    // Do something?
  } else {
    student = findUserInList(students, email, passwd);
    
    if (student) {
      alert("Welcome " + student.firstName + "! You are a student.");
      // Do something?
    } else {
      // We return, because there is nothing else to do
      return alert("This user/password combination was not found.");
    }
  }
  
  // I omitted the localStorage part because it did not make sense to me
  // as why you would do this, but it's syntactically correct, so feel free to add it
  // if it's a requirement
}
```

```css
label, input, button { display: block; max-width: 300px; margin-bottom: .5em; }
```

```html
<p>(Hint: the only valid user is <b>mayas.k@gmail.com</b> / <b>Mayas4ever</b>)</p>
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input id="email">
<label for="passwd">Password:</label>
<input id="passwd" type="password">
<button id="login-btn">Login</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help! I admit I have a bunch of mistakes there, but it's cause I'm extremely rusty at this and this assignment has had me battling for weeks. I only just sought out some help. I appreciate all the help and clarification on things I did!

Comment: I did a mistake with the strings, rather I was going to initiate res1/res2 to true/false and have it be called as Boolean(res1)/(res2). I also see the problem you mentioned with the password requirements. 

Blex you're amazing! Thanks a bunch!